# Passing parameters to `In` clause

Tags: sql, jasper-reports

I am trying to pass parameters to Jasper report `In` clause. Below is what I tried in Jasper reports.

```
SELECT * FROM `medication` WHERE $X{IN,idMeidication,$P!{parameter_name}}
```

However it is keep on saying the `parameter_name` does not exists. If I convert my Jasper SQL to normal SQL, it will look like this

```
SELECT * FROM `medication` WHERE idMedication IN (1,2,3)
```

I am using Jaspersoft Studio and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the right solution will be:

```
SELECT * FROM `medication` WHERE $X{IN,idMeidication,parameter_name}
```

without `$P!{}`

In this way i use it in my reports.